# Change single JOptionPane size

Tags: java, swing, layout

I need help changing the size of my TextField. I have a JScrollPane at the beginning of my panel (Which is big so I can read more data), then I have a JLabel for instructions and in the end I would like to add a JTextArea which I only need a row for entering a number. The problem is that the elements are quite big in the panel.
I attach the result:

[image: Layout]

Here is my code:

```
public static void delete()
{
    int deletePosition;
    String[] options = {"Confirm", "Cancel"};
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel label0 = new JLabel("Write the Position[#]:");
    JLabel labelJump1 = new JLabel("");
    JTextField txtDelete = new JTextField(1);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(0,1);
    panel.setLayout(gridLayout);

    String fullText = "";
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15,30);
        textArea.setText(fullText);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    panel.add(scrollPane);
    panel.add(label0);
    panel.add(labelJump1);
    panel.add(txtDelete);

    try
    {
        if (theEntityCollection.checkEmpty())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The collection is EMPTY");
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < theEntityCollection.getArraySize() ; i++)
            {

                fullText += "Position [" + (i+1) + "]\n\n" + theEntityCollection.getEntity(i);
                    if (i != theEntityCollection.getArraySize() - 1)
                        fullText += "_____________________\n\n"; 
                textArea.setText(fullText);
            }
            deletePosition = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "ENTITY COLLECTION", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options , options[0]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("FAILED");
    }
    fullText = "";
}
```

I must say that I'm new with the Java GUI.

I'll appreciate a lot if you could help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridLayout` is doing exactly what it was designed to do.  It provides each component with exactly the same amount of space evenly distributed based on the available space.  You'll probably need to use a more flexible layout manager, for example...

Start by chaning...

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(0,1);
panel.setLayout(gridLayout);
```

to something like...

```
GridBagLayout gridLayout = new GridBagLayout();
panel.setLayout(gridLayout);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
```

And then change...

```
panel.add(scrollPane);
panel.add(label0);
panel.add(labelJump1);
panel.add(txtDelete);
```

to something more like...

```
panel.add(scrollPane, gbc);
panel.add(label0, gbc);
panel.add(labelJump1, gbc);
panel.add(txtDelete, gbc);
```

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you very much.